# Python guessing game [Dice]

Tags: python

```
import random

number = random.randrange(1, 10)
print(number)
guess_count = 0
guess_limit = 3
out_of_gusses = False
guess = int(input("enter ur guess: "))

while guess > number or guess != number and not out_of_gusses:
    if guess > number:
        print("ur guess is higer than the number")
    else:
        print("ur guess is lower than the number:")

    if guess_count < guess_limit:
        guess = int(input("enter ur guess: "))
        guess_count += 1
    else:
        out_of_gusses = True

    if out_of_gusses:
        print("Out of guesses u lose: ")
    else:
        print("u Win")
```

my problem is that when i run the program and i did enter my number it says `u win` even though the number is wrong
and i also get 4 tries when the limit is set to 3 `guess:limit = 3`

iam new at coding so iam not to sure what the problem is but i think its somthing with the condintion of my while loop but cant quite get my head around how i should phase then

Comment: In the last if statement, either the `if` or the `else` is going to get executed in every loop, because the condition will be either `True` or `False`

Comment: Can you describe in your own words what the line `while guess > number or guess != number and not out_of_gusses:` should do?

Comment: ``while guess is greater than number print`` ur guess is higher than the number otherwise it most be ur guess is lower than the number

``or guess not equal to number`` - should do so it will give me another try since my guess is not  the right answer 

and not ``out_out_of_gusses:`` to keep track if iam out of gusses

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can restructure your entire logic into something simple that works:

```py
import random

number = random.randrange(1, 10)
print(number)
guess_count = 0
guess_limit = 3

while True:
    if guess_count < guess_limit:
        guess = int(input("enter ur guess: "))
        guess_count += 1
        if guess == number:
            print("u Win")
            break
    else:
        print("Out of guesses u lose: ")
        break
    
    if guess > number:
        print("ur guess is higer than the number")
    elif guess < number:
        print("ur guess is lower than the number:")
```

Basically, you create an infinite loop that you break out of, if the guess is correct or if they have run out of guesses. This way, you can have your entire dice game logic into that `while` loop.

Comment: so a while True loop is better if there only 2 options? than a making it the way i did? i did also try making the ``guess = int(input("enter ur guess"))`` but it gave me so problems since i didn't use the ``int`` at the start was not entirely sure what it did and how to use it iam sure it shows aswell, i should probbaly read up on that. but i had problems with putting ``ur guess is higher/lower than the number" at the bottom i had to put it above ``guess_count``

Comment: it doesn't matter how many options there are. The code I show above is simply more concise, because you handle everything inside the loop, without having to ask for a number outside the loop.

Comment: ``if guess > number:``

why does it end with ``elif`` and not ``else`` i thought they had to end on ``else``

Comment: Because if the guess is equal to the number, the `else` clause would still be executed, which is not what you want. You want to print those messages if the guess is strictly less or greater than the number

Answer (score 0):

There are a few flaws in your code

```
while guess > number or guess != number and not out_of_gusses:
```

This resolves to

```
while guess != number and not out_of_gusses:
```

because whenever `guess > number` is `true`, `guess != number` is anyway `true`.
That also means that if your guess is correct in the first place, the while loop is not executed at all.

The problem with your off by one `guess_count` comes from the fact that you're initializing `guess_count` with 0 ignoring the initial guess.

```
if out_of_gusses:
  print("Out of guesses u lose: ")
else:
  print("u Win")
```

This conclusion is not correct, just because you're not out of guesses doesn't mean you won!

Comment: for that line of code i thought if iam not out of gusses the player most have won then.